# Pandas group double observations by aggregating column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+----------+---------+
| username | role    |
+----------+---------+
| foo      | user    |
+----------+---------+
| foo      | analyst |
+----------+---------+
| bar      | admin   |
+----------+---------+
```

and I would like to remove the repetition of the users that appear twice or more by aggregating the column role in a way to obtain the following dataframe:

```
+----------+---------------+
| username | role          |
+----------+---------------+
| foo      | user, analyst |
+----------+---------------+
| bar      | admin         |
+----------+---------------+
```

So far I have tried using pivot table in this way:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='username', columns='role')
```

and also the `groupby` function, but this is not the right way to do it.
What is the right way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list or comma separate strings using the following:

```
df.groupby('username')['role'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  username             role
0      bar          [admin]
1      foo  [user, analyst]
```

OR

```
df.groupby('username')['role'].agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()
```

OUtput:

```
  username           role
0      bar          admin
1      foo  user, analyst
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is group the rows based on `username`, so the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html)-function is one way to go. Usually when you use `groupby` you apply an [aggregation function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) to the rest of the columns, for example `sum`, `average`, `min` or similair. But you can also define your own aggregation function, and use that in `agg`.

```
def merge_strings(series):
    # This function will get a series of all the values in a column. For example for foo the series will be ['user', 'analyst'].
    # We can use the built in function str.cat() fo contatenate a series of strings.

    return series.str.cat(sep=', ')
```

Then we simply call groupby, and tell that we want to aggregate the `role`-column using our custom function

```
df.groupby('username').agg({'role': merge_strings})
```